# How to extend the return type of a function passing the parameter type?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to define an interface extending properties from the return type of an existing function.
But the function has its return type defined by a parameter type. Something like the code below:

```js
function doSomething<T: any>(myParameter: T): { myProperty: T };
```

```js
interface MyInterface<A> extends ReturnType<typeof doSomething<A>> {
  newProperty1: boolean;
  newProperty2: boolean;
}
```

Then, when I use the interface, I would like to infer the function's parameter type, like

```js
let something: MyInterface<number>;
```

resulting in a type like

```js
{
  myProperty: number,
  newProperty1: boolean,
  newProperty2: boolean,
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, I don't think you can reuse the signature of `doSomething`. As a workaround, you could re-define it by using an interface.

```
interface MyCallSignature<T> {
  (myParameter: T): {
    myParameter: T
  }
}

interface MyInterface<T> extends ReturnType<MyCallSignature<T>> {
  newProperty1: boolean;
  newProperty2: boolean;
}

declare let something: MyInterface<number>;

something.myProperty; // number
something.newProperty1; // boolean
something.newProperty2; // boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

```js
function doSomething<T extends any = {}>(myParameter: T): { myProperty: T } {
  return { myProperty: myParameter }
}

type DoSomething<T> = typeof doSomething
type MyInterface<A extends any = {}> = ReturnType<DoSomething<A>> & {
  newProperty1: boolean
  newProperty2: boolean
}

const something: MyInterface<number> = {
  myProperty: 1,
  newProperty1: true,
  newProperty2: false
}
```

Comment: Hi Simon, thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, in my case, the function doSomething comes from an external library and I need use the typeof operator in order to get its type.

Comment: Hi @BrunoCorreia, I have edited my answer, but still not working. The issue here is Typescript won't let you pass generic to your `typeof doSomething<T>`. This thread could help: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20719